# Can't read image in Android Emulator

Tags: android, linux, permissions, android-emulator

Ok, I'm really lost here: I have an app that is supposed to take a picture (with Camera Intent) and display it in an image view.

No matter what I do, I can't make it work in the emulator, it takes the picture ok (checked it with adb shell on virtual sd folder: files are there), saves it to virtual SD card ... but is not able to read it in order to display it in ImageView, it keeps throwing:

**W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/0CE8-3A18/pics/IMG_XXXXXXXXXX.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**

Odd thing is that this happens only in emulator, when deployed on my phone, it works just fine (takes the picture and displays it in ImageView)

I am using Android Studio 1.3.2 on Linux Mint 17.2 (64 bits) and my manifest has:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />`

And the code to retrieve saved image and display on ImageView:

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
            /*************************************************
            //THIS IS THE CODE THAT FAILS, ONLY IN EMULATOR
            ***************************************************/
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 300, 300, false);
                showImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
          { 
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){ 
          // User cancelled the image capture 
          } else { 
          // Image capture failed, advise user } }
          }
     }
```

I don't know why this happens, I am thinking that it might had to do with some obscure Linux permission rule for emulators or something... any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead of loading from MediaStore:

`bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri);
showImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

Comment: Hi L.Swifter, I tried:

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri.getPath());

Because decodeFile takes a String as argument, but still it keeps throwing same error:

E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/0CE8-3A18/pics/IMG_20151015_235105.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

I'm starting to think that Camera Intent might not be saving them in proper format, or files get corrupted when saved...

Next thing I'm gonna try is to add an image into virtual SD Card, then try to load that image from program using same code, and see how it goes....

Comment: I tried today, both your and my methods worked on my emulator ( android studio 2.1, ubuntu). It's hard to get the reason, maybe it's better to let this question go.